# How to refresh the combobox ItemSource after loading?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I am new to WPF:

I have a combobox whose ItemsSource is changing. This is not being reflected back to the user. Do i have to specify the ItemsSource Mode to TwoWay?

Any Suggessions?

```
<ComboBox Height="Auto" Name="comboBoxQuery" Width="300" IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding QueryNames, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedQueryNames, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" Visibility="Collapsed" /> <!--Is this correct? -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to tell the view that collection source was changed, you should use collection classes which supports **INotifyCollectionChanged** interface. For example: **ObservableCollection**, **BindingList**. You do not need TwoWay data binding, WPF will detect that source collection supports **INotifyCollectionChanged** interface, and all changes you made in that collection will reflect the view.